# Problema al crear un array con php con tildes

Tags: php, array, tildes

Tengo un código simple para crear un array en php con diferentes valores:

```
$ufs[] = array('id'=> $id, 'name'=> $name, 'proveidors'=> $proveidors);
```

El problema es que al incluir en la variable $proveidors palabras con tildes el resultado es erroneo:

"Arròs Estany de Pals" se convierte en "Arr\u00f2s Estany de Pals", 
"Vins Parés" se convierte en "Vins Par\u00e9s"

He buscado soluciones como header('content-type: text/html; charset=utf-8'); utf8_encode()... pero ninguna ha funcionado. Alguna idea?

Gracias por adelantado!

Comment: tengo el mismo problema lo pudiste solucionar?

Answer (score 0):

Si estas mostrando los datos en una pagina, coloca dentro de la etiqueta  `<head>` lo siguiente: 
`<meta charset="utf-8">`

Comment: por que tiene que usar esa etiqueta, que tal si argumentas mejor tu respuesta, saludos.